# Relating the derivative of the inverse function with the derivative of the function using calculus

Tags: calculus

I wanted to see if I can express the derivative of the inverse function using the derivative of the function.

So, $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has an inverse $s(y) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $y = f(s)$.

The definition of the derivative gives

$$\lim_{\Delta s \to 0} \frac{f(s + \Delta s) - f(s)}{\Delta s} = f'(s) \quad (1)$$

$$\lim_{\Delta y \to 0} \frac{s(y + \Delta y) - s(y)}{\Delta y} = s'(y) \quad (2)$$

If

$$\lim_{\Delta y \to 0} s(y + \Delta y) - s(y) = 0 = \lim_{\Delta s \to 0} \Delta s \quad (3)$$

and

$$\lim_{\Delta s \to 0} f(s + \Delta s) - f(s) = 0 = \lim_{\Delta y \to 0} \Delta y \quad (4)$$

then

**Edit (amd)**:

$$f'(s)s'(y) = \lim_{\Delta s, \Delta y \to 0} \frac{f(s + \Delta s) - f(s)}{\Delta s}{\frac{s(y + \Delta y) - s(y)}{\Delta y} } = 1$$

so

$$s'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(s)}, \quad f'(s) \ne 0$$

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: The usual way to prove this is to use the chain rule.

Comment: What if either of those derivatives vanishes?

Comment: @amd: OK, but is there anything wrong with it? Vanishing: if the result is correct, then $f'(s) \ne 0$.